# How to use facebook comments with django

Tags: html, django, facebook

I have a blog web site, where I have 7 apps in which I post with django admin. Every app has the simplest view (the views that call, filter the objects and return the template) and the post_detail view, that open another template where is showed informations about only one post. I don't have slug in my posts, I am sorry because I have a litle idea of what is this, but I think I have unique urls, because the posts urls are automatically called by regex. So, I am trying to put facebook comments plugin in my website, but when I put the facebook comments, I cant list the comment with the respective post. I am sorry, I have no idea what is the correct way to do this. I would like to know what I have to do to list facebook comments with my posts. Very thanks, the code is below:

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    posts = Evento.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Evento, pk=pk)
    Evento.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'core/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

models.py:

```
class Evento(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    apresentacao = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    foto = CloudinaryField('foto', null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

index.html

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class=item>
            <p><h1><a href="{% url 'core:detalhe' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.nome }}</a></h1></p>
            <center><img>{% cloudinary post.foto %}</img></center>
            <p><h2>{{ post.apresentacao }}</h2></p>
            <br>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

post_detail.html:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Evento
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def index(request):
    posts = Evento.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, 'core/index.html', {'posts': posts})


def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Evento, pk=pk)
    Evento.objects.get(pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'core/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

I don't know how to create a new facebook comments to each new post, I just can use the same for every posts. Very thanks everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this script after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/id_ID/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.10";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  .....
```

And then, in your `core/post_detail.html` or inside your `{% for` loop, change `data-href=""` with your detail post url.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{% url 'core:detalhe' pk=post.pk %}" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

For more efficient you can use [`request.get_full_path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri), but `request.get_full_path` allow the query strings from `GET` parameters.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="{{ request.get_full_path }}" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

See [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/) for more information.

Example inside the loop:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="item">
    <h1>{{ post.nome }}</h1>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-numposts="5"
         data-href="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{% url 'core:detalhe' pk=post.pk %}">
    </div>
    ....
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Example inside `core/post_detail.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}{{ post.nome }} - {{ block.super }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="detail-post">
    <h1>{{ post.nome }}</h1>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-numposts="5"
         data-href="http://{{ request.META.HTTP_HOST }}{% url 'core:detalhe' pk=post.pk %}">
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I don't know if is happening because I am running locally, but I can't post and have some comments dated a few months in my posts. I'll try to deploy.